# Disable user access control programmatically for running commands in console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I created a console application for run the command prompt. Now i want to disable the user access control permission while running the .exe file. Please resolve the issue.

I have to run this command from administrator. I changed the requireAdministrator in manifest. But i want disable the user access control permission.

Here is my code :

```
        Process cmd  = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
        cmd.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: You can't disable UAC.  If you could everyone would and then UAC would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your host-program (Shift + right-click -> run as) as the user you want to run your cmd.exe, it should automatically run the cmd.exe you start in your program as the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Your application can't programmatically control the UAC behaviour because is a system-level security feature.

What you can do, **on your system** (where you are administrator) ,  is to create an elevated shortcut to your application exe and use that to open the app and avoid the UAC dialog.

See here:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-elevated-shortcut-run-programs-bypass-uac